# RealSenso No IR Image, and broken Depth Image on Four SR300

Tags: rgb, depth, infrared, realsense

Folks,

I left four of my realsense SR300 running for 16 hours, only streaming Depth images, and nothing else. Now I am checking the images, and my Depth image on all four sensors are messed up. When I run the cpp-capture.cpp example, I cannot see my IR image, and the Depth is weird. This is happening on all four sensors equally, as I just test each one individually, turned off, and then back on (full shutdown) my computer, and unplugged, and plugged back in each sensor. Why is this happening? I bought the sensors this week, and started using them since Tuesday, February 21st, 2017 (two days ago). See image Below (IR is completely dark, and Depth has that weird pink color. Only RGB is image is working well on all four sensors):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redo the Video4Linux backend preparation to apply the kernel patches. And that solved my problem. I wonder why, though, is this not a persistent thing?